# Why is Gerald McCloy able to imitate sound effects only?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, analysis, animation, gerald-mcboingboing

I recall watching 2005 TV series *Gerald McBoing-Boing*.

He was a human child living with his parents and their dog. He also had several friends of his age.

But he was odd. He was communicating with people only by imitating sound effects (telephone ringing, etc.). Of course his imitations were 100% perfect. They couldn't be differentiated from real sounds.

He could realize people's speakings. But he himself wasn't able to speak with words (or even to imitate them).

**My Question**: Is there any explanation (in- or out-of-univsrse) on why Gerald was able to imitate sound effects only and how he was so good at it?

Note: McBoing-Boing was his nickname given to him by his friends. His surname was McCloy as you see in the title.

Comment: Why does this have a close vote on it?  This question is perfectly acceptable for this site.  Stop slapping close votes on acceptable questions, people!

Comment: That was my close vote, and I VTCed because I believe it is opinion-based. The origin of Gerald's strange characteristic is not addressed in the series because it is not deemed important. It's like asking why Roadrunner always seems to be one step ahead of Wile E. Coyote, or how Finn is able to hide his beautiful hair under a small white hat: *artistic license*, used for its effect on a story, analysis of which won't affect the significance of the story.

Comment: "*It's like asking why Roadrunner always seems to be one step ahead of Wile E. Coyote*": nope! This is **not** opinion-based. According to Ian Frazier, it's because of [gross negligence & product liability](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1990/02/26/coyote-v-acme). Facts! ^^

Comment: @Joachim - you answered the first part of the question _"Is there any explanation (in or out-of-universe)"_ with an answer of no, there was no in-universe explanation. Your down vote seems to imply that you don't think that it was valid to ask if there were any in-universe explanations, or to ask about out-of universe explanations.  I realize that a negative can't be proven so there may not be a definitive answer to the out-of universe question (i.e. "no" is not a valid answer to the out-of-universe question), but there could be a yes answer out there, statements by the creator(s) for example.

Comment: @StevePemberton It wasn't Joachim who answered my question. It was blobbymcblooby.

Comment: @EtackSxchange - I know. Joachim said that they downvoted the question and they gave their reason why. I was pointing out that in their objection they were actually answering the first part of your question.

Comment: @Joachim: Opinion-based should only be used when the response _can only be_ opinion-based, without a priori-knowledge of the response itself. For example, someone asking the best movies of all times is necessarily opinion-based. If there are objective answers (such as "no in-universe reason was given") and answerers start speculating/giving their opinion, the problem is not with the question, but with the answers which speculate/opine.

Comment: @StevePemberton I did not downvote, and did not say I did :) (I downvote very little because I find it extremely dissuading myself).

Comment: But hey, I retracted my close vote. I just got [my most upvoted question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97259/) downvoted for what I can only assume to be an attempt at revenge, which is not worth sticking my neck out for. (Also, @MatthieuM. makes a good point, and I judged based on prior knowledge .)

Comment: @Joachim Please don't think I'm behind that downvote on your question!

Comment: @Joachim - I apologize I misread your comment, you did in fact say vote to close.  Opinions about opinion based questions (I can't think of better way to say that) will naturally vary. Unprovables like "best movie ever made" are of course obviously better discussed in an opinion forum. I tend to feel that if there is a truth or fact possibly out there but currently unknown, I don't mind some speculation about it.  But it becomes a gray area at times.

Comment: @Joachim Kudos to you for stating that you put the close vote on this question!  Thank you for the explanation.  It's refreshing to have close voters explain _why_ they close voted.  Also, +1 for your most upvoted question!  Great question! :)

Comment: "But he himself wasn't able to speak with words (or even to imitate them)."

Is it ever explicitly mentioned that he wasn't _able_ to speak with words?  
Some neurodivergent people are nonverbal, and many neurodivergent people actively imitate non-speech sounds. To me, at least, Gerald McCloy's case sounds like a stronger (and/or more movie-logic-themed) version of [nonverbal autism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonverbal_autism).

I'd be very surprised if anything like that made it into an _official_ explanation, however! So I apologize if you're asking for an official explanation.

Comment: I wish the sole downvoter also commented to help improve this post.

Comment: Broadly because that's the sole point of McBoing-Boing's existence.

I had a school-friend who tried to work that way.

More importantly, consider (that guy) in the Police Academy series whose meaningful contribution is solely to provide useful sound effects… 

Square Police Academy guy's characteristics and do you not wind up with  McBoing-Boing?

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: (as question was updated)

> Is there any explanation (in- or out-of-univsrse) on why Gerald was able to imitate sound effects only and how he was so good at it?

Out of universe, and going back to 1950, no, there does not seem to be an explanation for him.

In-universe, unless there was an opportunity to expand and explain this in the 2005 remake that you missed (*because I haven't watched any of them*), then no.

- Gerald McBoing-Boing is a *Dr. Seuss* script that was made into a record for release in 1950.
- Dr. Seuss's script *consisted almost entirely of voice-overs and sound effects*
- With the success of the record, it became an animation (but not in Dr. Seuss style) from studio UPA which incidentally would become known for the Mr. Magoo animations, which is why the animation style and look is similar.
- Gerald McBoing-Boing later became a book in 1952 after the success of the animation.
- Dr Seuss' artwork has been described as surrealist, and as such his subjects and stories are rarely relatable to the real world, but do take inspiration from it (often from where he lived).
- the 2005 TV series was a remake, hoping to kick start a revival of the character which ultimately failed.
- Note: In both the original artwork, and then the subsequent book artwork, he is depicted as a human boy, so he is unlikely to be thought of as anything but that, as likely intended by the author.

So, based on the above, and that the OP's question is about a remake, and given the origins of the original, it is very unlikely that the character would be explained in a satisfactory way for the OP. *Gerald is simply a little human boy that started exhibiting this strange feature at age 2.*

Whilst some of the characters might be human, the *Sam-I-Am* or *The Lorax* creatures, for example, are never explained.

[image]

1952 art, 1953 Dr Seuss art, 2005 remake

http://toonopedia.com/gerald.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20161006090724/http://scottsantoro.blogspot.com/2012/03/gerald-mcboing-boing-rare-seuss-artwork.html

https://seuss.fandom.com/wiki/Gerald_McCloy

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32682124-gerald-mcboing-boing

https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/43013/gerald-mcboing-boing-by-dr-seuss-illustrated-by-mel-crawford/

Recording, the origin of Gerald:

Comic book references:

https://comicbookplus.com/?dlid=36161

https://www.comics.org/issue/226954/

https://comics.ha.com/comic-issue-index/the-comics-journal.s?id=943331

All indicate that he is simply a human boy that is suddenly affected by this:

> "UPA presents"; Illustrated script of a recording originally by Dr. Seuss. The Toon Treasury reprint credits the art to P.D. Eastman. Here's the *script from the first two panels*: **"This is the story of Gerald McCloy... ...and the strange thing that happened to that little boy."**

Comment: I removed that part about my thought from the question.

Comment: edited to address the difference

Comment: That quoted part was in the question from the start

Comment: I included that to narrow down the response in my answer, as in OP asks this question, answer is yes or no, then i blah blah afterwards - i didnt have that part before. The response to the opinion i left in by mistake and is now removed.

Comment: "*..it is very unlikely that the character would be explained in a satisfactory way for the OP.*" Kind of my point :)